# How do I pass parameters day, month and year using select_date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-2

I have the following `date_select`, which displays three drop-down menus, from which I can select the month, day, and year.

```
<%=date_select("dateName", "dateMethod", :order => [:month, :day, :year])%>
```

I don't know how to pass the parameters to the next page. How can I pass the month, day and year with a `submit_tag` or a `link_to`? I am in a view page named `generateDataForReport`, and I want to catch the parameters in another view under the same controller named `showGeneratedReport`.

Comment: Can you post the entire form? Are you using `form_for`? The submit button would submit to what ever is called in the `form_for` tag. What does your controller look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your console when you submit the form, you can see how these parameters are named:

```
"dateName"=>{"dateMethod(2i)"=>"12", "dateMethod(3i)"=>"1", "dateMethod(1i)"=>"2013"
```

In your controller, you can grab the parameters like this:

Year:

```
params[:dateName]['dateMethod(1i)']
```

Month:

```
params[:dateName]['dateMethod(2i)']
```

Day:

```
params[:dateName]['dateMethod(3i)']
```

You can assign them to variables in your controller to make them easier to deal with:

```
day = params[:dateName]['dateMethod(3i)']
month = params[:dateName]['dateMethod(2i)']
year = params[:dateName]['dateMethod(1i)']
```

If you want to pass these params to your next page, then do this in your redirect:

```
redirect_to report_path(@report, :d => day, :m => month, :y => year)
```

Now on the next page, your URL should look something like this showing your params:

```
http://localhost:3000/reports/28?d=1&m=12&y=2013
```

Now to display them on the page you do this:

```
  <%= params[:d] %>
  <%= params[:m] %>
  <%= params[:y] %>
```